# Why is both reference change and primitive change catch by Angular2 during change detection even with OnPush flag set?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-changedetection

Consider the following [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/6kjmtqrnoPAsICFqH9xD?p=preview)

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, DoCheck, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child1',
  template: `
    <div>reference change for entire object: {{my_obj1.name}}</div>
    <div>reassign primitive in property of object: {{my_obj2.name}}</div>
    <div>update primitive in property of object: {{my_obj2.num}}</div>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Child1 {

  @Input()
  my_obj1: Object = {'name': ''};

  @Input()
  my_obj2: Object = {'name': '', 'num': 0};

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('check from child1');
    console.log(this.my_obj1);
    console.log(this.my_obj2);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <div>
      <child1
        [my_obj1]="my_obj1"
        [my_obj2]="my_obj2"
      >
      </child1>
      <button (click)="change_obj1()">
        Change obj1
      </button>

    </div>
    `,
  directives: [Child1]
})
export class App {

  my_obj1: Object = {'name': 'name1'};
  my_obj2: Object = {'name': 'name2', 'num': 0};

  change_obj1() {
    this.my_obj1 = {'name': 'change1'}
    this.my_obj2['name'] = 'change2';
    this.my_obj2['num'] += 1;
  }
}
```

From the experiment I made, here is my understanding of the current `Angular2` change detection strategy, can someone verify it if its true?

1. Angular2 by default checks for value equality when doing change detection. If there are no `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, every watched variable in component tree is checked for value equality. If value equality is false, that specific component will be rerender, and if value equality if true, that specific component will not be rerender.
2. If you add `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to a component. The behavior changes as follows

   i. If variable inside the component have reference change, the component is rerendered, and child component is checked for change detection (its specific change detection algorithm value/reference check depends on `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`)

   ii. If variable inside the component don't have reference change, the component is not rerendered, and child component is not checked for change detection, regardless of presence of `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Is this the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reworked your plunker a bit: [new plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vixCWprOdDA6nJ6VjigN?p=preview)

Since primitive values are [immutable](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch01.html#_primitive_values), there is no difference between reassigning and updating – the primitive gets the new immutable value, so I removed the "updating" code.  Also, it is very helpful to split out assigning a new object reference (which does trigger change detection) and assigning a new primitive value (which does not trigger change detection). So I did that also.

If you run my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vixCWprOdDA6nJ6VjigN?p=preview) we can make the following observations:

1. changing an input property that is a **reference type** on an `OnPush` component 
   **will update** the component's view.  The template bindings are checked for changes.  In addition, child components are checked (assuming they are not using `OnPush`).
2. changing a primitive property that is contained within a reference type on an `OnPush` component **will not update** the component's view.  The template bindings are not checked for changes.  In addition, child components are not checked, regardless of whether they are using `OnPush` or not.
3. `ngDoCheck()` is always called on the first `OnPush` component, **regardless** of whether the template bindings are checked for change or not.  I find this odd (who knows, maybe it is a bug).  So, just because `ngDoCheck()` is called does not necessarily imply that template bindings are checked.

---

Note, when a template binding change is detected, only that change is propagated to a child component or the DOM (as appropriate, depending on the binding type).  If the binding change resulted in a DOM change, the entire component is not rerendered.  Only that bound DOM data is updated, and the browser will only then update that one DOM element.  (This is unlike some other frameworks, where they do rerender the entire template if any change is found.  This helps make Angular faster.)

Answer (score 0):

This post explains it in detail pretty well:

http://victorsavkin.com/post/133936129316/angular-immutability-and-encapsulation

In short you're assumptions are correct. Angular2 must be conservative and check for value equality, i.e. it must do a 'deep check' of the objects referenced.

With `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, components will only be updated if the references to their input objects have changed.

Thus is why immutable objects can be preferred data structures--if we must update an object, the component is now referencing a new object. And it is therefore easy for angular to know which components must be updated.

Performant behavior can also be achieved with observables, through the `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck();` method.

This is explained here:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "deep check"?

Comment: It must check the object and all of it's properties. This is faster than the angular 1 version though, which would do something like ```oldValue.prop1 === newValue.prop1``` because angular2 creates change detector classes at runtime, which are monomorphic (angular1 checks are polymorphic). Learn more -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvKGQSFQf10

Comment: That's what I thought you meant, but I wanted to check before I commented.  My understanding is that Angular 2 does not check all of the properties of objects, hence it does not do "deep checking" of objects.  Rather, it only checks the properties that are used in template bindings.  So if we have an object with 20 properties, but only one of them has a template binding, then the associated change detector class only checks that one property.  This blog says the same: http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/#andwhataboutthenestedobjectowner